# Word for going to ground floor

Tags: idioms, sentence

In a multi-story building when we go to ground floor from an upper floor, what word is used? Downstairs? Any other word?

For example, when I go to the ground floor by elevator, should I say, "I am going downstairs?"

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If you step into an elevator, one can ask "Going down?" But downstairs is also a place, so you can take the elevator downstairs

Comment: Would you use descend in a sentence telling people where you are going? I would use it for someone in a ball gown descending the large manor staircase

Comment: One word: "Down" and it works. That's what most people say most of the time.

Comment: In dictionaries it is not explained that downstair world can be used only when using stairs or elevator or both. I think "downstair" word can be used when we go to lower floors through stairs not elevator, if this is true then what word is used when we go to lower floors through elevator

Comment: @Susan Though I'm not a native speaker this **I'm going downstairs** seems applicable only in context of going down the stairs. And what's wrong with **I'm going down/I'm coming**? **Descend** sounds like a scientific term.

Comment: I just shared my understanding. Thank you, I didn't know that **descend** may be applyed in this context.

Comment: You most probably know this but just in case... _downstairs_ doesn't apply to _ground floor_ only.. You can climb down from 4th to 2nd floor and it still is _"going downstairs"_

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. Starting with yours, going downstairs implies *using the steps*. That's fine if that's what you're doing.

If you are facing an elevator, and you want to ask people if the elevator is heading down, you can ask, as mplungin stated, *"Going down?"* (A shortened form of *Are you going down to...?*)

If you step into an elevator, and want to know if it's going down, you can say, *"Is this going down?"* "*Are we going down?"* "*Is this/are we going up or down?"*

If you want to tell people you want to descend, you can say, "*I'm going down*," or "*Going down.*"

Answer (score 1):

AHD licenses the extended usage:

**downstairs ...**

**adv.**

1. Down the stairs: raced my friend downstairs.
2. To or on a lower floor: waited downstairs while her parents were getting dressed.

**n.** (used with a sing. verb)

The lower or main floor.

**adj.** downstairs also downstair

Located on a lower or main floor.